# python not running with multiple versions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this serious problem with my fedora installation. I was trying to use one of my application that requires Python3. So, as a new Linux user, I simply installed python3. Hence my system for two python versions (3 & 2.7). I guess python3 replaced python2.7. Hence "yum" stopped working. I tried to link /usr/bin/python to python2.7 and removing "PYTHONPATH" from .bashrc. 
Now when i am running-

```
 $python -V

Python2.7.8
```

When I try to run python itself it returns as -

```
$ python
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site.py", line 176
      file=sys.stderr)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

when I am running yum I get following result -

```
$yum
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am thinking of removing all the python versions from the terminal and then reinstall.

Can somebody help me with this situation? Please help me to correct my system!

Thank you 
Amol

Comment: Have you try to run python3 command on terminal ? what would be the output?

Comment: How did you install Python 3? Either way, undo all manual changes (symlinks, PYTHONPATH, etc) and then check for instructions how to install Python 3 using your distro's package manager. After that, `python` should point to Python 2 while `python3` will point to Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bit onto your variables, it seems like you have a syslink pointing to a weird place that holds a python interpreter that is not the default interpreter.

The output of your

```
#ls -al /usr/bin/python
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Oct 23 16:37 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
```

that exactly shows what i mean, what you need to do is make that syslink point to the right python interpreter that should be at /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -> python2.7

so the previous command should give you a:

```
#ls -al /usr/bin/python
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Oct 23 16:37 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

that could be done with a syslink create command, check the proper documentation to create or modify an existing syslink in fedora 21

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131590/discussion-on-answer-by-dyelamos-python-not-running-with-multiple-versions).